# winforms and metroframework shows two scrollbars in metrogrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar, metroframework

I'm using metroframework for my application but the issue is that in metroGrid (dataGridView)  shows two scrollbars, the metro one and the default one as the picture shows:

[image: two scrollbars on gridview]

I've tried to set scrollbars property to none but it hides both bars..